# PHP in_array with regexp haystack array

Tags: php, preg-match

Does the PHP function `in_array` accept a REGEXP array as second argument ?
I couldn't find any relevant information on [PHP.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.in-array.php)

This is the code I'm currently using :

```
$haystack = [
    "/^foo$/",
    "/^bar$/",
    "/^foobar$/"
];

function in_reg_array($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $straw)
        if (preg_match($straw, $needle))
            return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
```

If anyone has a better solution, I'm open to suggestions.

#### Edit :

I can't use a single regexp with `foo|bar|foobar` because the haystack varies.

Comment: `preg_grep('/^(foo|bar|foobar)$/",` ?

Comment: I know this, but this is a sample, the one I use has variable amount of regexes.

Comment: `preg_grep("/^(".implode('|',$haystack).")$/"` ?

Comment: In @FelippeDuarte suggestion, remember that `$haystack` should not contain `/^` and `$/`, so `$haystack = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_filter()` takes an array of patterns, replaces them, and returns the replaced string. So, if it returns nothing, then you know there were no matches.

```
function in_reg_array($needle, $haystack) {
    return preg_filter($haystack, '', $needle) !== null;
}
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of `preg_filter` earlier ? ^^

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
$haystack = [
    "^foo$",
    "^bar$",
    "^foobar$"
];

$string = ['foo', 'bar','baz', 'foo2'];

$result = preg_grep("/(".implode('|',$haystack).")/", $string);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(3) "foo"
  [1]=> string(3) "bar"
}
```